# Priority order when declaring more than one class in a html tag

Tags: html, css, tags

More than one class can be declared in a single tag, as an exampled given in this same forum:

`<a href="#" class="class1 class2">My Text</a>`

But, in case of conflict of styles, which class prevails? class1, or class2?

Comment: make sense to read the doc:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="class2 class1"> Random DIV </div>

<style>

.class1{
    background-color: blue;
}

.class2{
    background-color: red;
}

</style>

</body>
</html>
```

Given this simple HTML, the div will be colored in red, since, in the `<style>` tag, the class2 is defined last compared to the class1

Answer (score 0):

As MUL8RSlftware wrote in this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="class2 class1"> Random DIV </div>


<style>
.class1{
    background-color: blue;
}

.class2{
    background-color: red;
}


<style>

</body>
</html>
```

The **red** color will be applied. But you also have to have `specificity` in mind.

What I mean by that is in this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div>
 <div class="class2 class1"> Random DIV </div>
</div>

<style>

div > .class1{
    background-color: blue;
}

.class2{
    background-color: red;
}


<style>

</body>
</html>
```

It will be **blue**, because its more specific.

Answer (score 0):

The **last** one declared in the `CSS` code will be used :

> `class2` will be applied.

```css
.class1 {
  background: red;
}

.class2 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="class1 class2">My Text</a>
```

> `class1` will be applied.

```css
.class2 {
  background: green;
}

.class1 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="class1 class2">My Text</a>
```